# What's the advantage of preparing a matrix to return in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

It's the code in the book 'Machine Learning in Action'. [source code](https://github.com/pbharrin/machinelearninginaction/blob/master/Ch02/kNN.py)

And the what is passed to `dataSet` is a m * 3 array(`datingTestSet2.txt` which can be found in the superior directory. )

My question is:

What's the advantage of preparing a matrix to return? (conserve memory?)

If I don't prepare the matrix, will it go wrong? (It seems not.)

```
from numpy import *
def autoNorm(dataSet):
    minVals = dataSet.min(0)
    maxVals = dataSet.max(0)
    ranges = maxVals - minVals
    normDataSet = zeros(shape(dataSet)) # prepare matrix to return(It's my own comment, not in the source code. )
    # Because there is a similar code before it, 
    # I think it should be the same meaning. Or any means else?
    m = dataSet.shape[0]
    normDataSet = dataSet - tile(minVals, (m,1))
    normDataSet = normDataSet/tile(ranges, (m,1))   #element wise divide
    return normDataSet, ranges, minVals
```

Comment: Is that the exact code from the book? If so, the line you're asking about is redundant, since `normDataSet` gets bound to something else two lines later. (A checker like `pyflakes` would flag this line.)

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Yes, it is. And it's the source code.[link](https://github.com/pbharrin/machinelearninginaction/blob/master/Ch02/kNN.py) I thought the author did it on purpose, or a good program style.

Comment: Nope. As you suspect, that line has no value (or possibly negative value). It's definitely not good program style. It might be that the author intended the next assignment to `normDataSet` to be a slice assignment instead, in which case the "prepare matrix" line could make sense.

Comment: No such "prepare matrix to return" comment appears in the code you linked. It only shows up on a completely different line, one that has an actual point. This assignment looks like it was left in by mistake.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry. But what's the means of this code, if it's not preparing a matrix to return?

Comment: @Vansiee: Like I said, it seems to just be left in by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no advantage. In the code you show, the first assignment to `normDataSet` has no lasting effect, because two lines later there's a second assignment to `normDataSet`. At that point, the reference count of the `zeros` array object that was previously bound to `normDataSet` reaches zero, and that old array is immediately garbage collected. (This is assuming CPython, of course, but at the time of writing none of the alternative Python implementations has fully working support for NumPy.)

I'd guess that this is a simple (but relatively harmless) error on the author's part. I'd suggest submitting a bug report so that it can be fixed.

By the way, a terminology nit: `normDataSet` is an *array*, not a *matrix*. This matters because NumPy *does* have a `matrix` type, whose behaviour on multiplication, division and exponentiation differs from that of a regular `array`.

Comment: Excellent remark on array vs matrix. I just want to add that using the `numpy.matrix` type is a really bad idea since it can result in hard to catch errors since its type is "contagious". I.e. using it in one place in the code can make calculations in some *other* piece of unrelated code suddenly use matrix operations instead of array operations. It's much better to use `numpy.dot()` or the (god sent) matrix operator `@` of Python 3.5+.

Comment: @HannesOvrén: Agreed - there are many reasons not to use `numpy.matrix`. The contagion you mention, the fact that it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle, its lack of direct support for some basic operations (e.g., `large_matrix.min()` first turns `large_matrix` into an array, making a full copy!). `@` is nice, but unfortunately, it's going to be a long wait for Python 3.5 for many corporate Python users. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In addition to being unnecessary to initialize normDataSet, it is not needed at all. You can directly modify the `array` dataSet points to without affecting the passed in `array`.

The code in general is overly verbose and complicated, and does not use `numpy`to its full effect. I'm not aware of a buit-in function to renormalize an `array` to the range [0,1] in `numpy`, but it can be easily done using element-wise operations on a `numpy` `array`:

```
def autoNorm(dataSet):
    minVals = dataSet.min(0)
    ranges = dataSet.max(0) - minVals
    dataSet = (dataSet-minVals) / ranges
    return dataSet, ranges, minVals
```

Comment: I am sorry. The dataSet is a m*3 array. I forget to state it.